# Downsize 3 queries to a single SQL query for server-side pagination

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony

Essentially I need to recover the result of 3 queries, in a single query (for server-side pagination ordering).
This is a little intricate.

Here is the diagram containing the required fields.

[image: e]

Two column results I need are considered of function related tasks (count).

This first query successfully recover all rows, except two, that i need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vue_cdc_for_opera.libelle as CDC,
                               vue_cdc_for_opera.id_cdc as \"id\",
                               COALESCE(vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_ue, vue_cdc_for_opera.signe_fr) as Signe,
                               vue_cdc_for_opera.classe_ue as \"Classe produit\",
                               vue_cdc_for_opera.code_cdc as \"Code CDC\",
                               dt_bdd_produit.libelle_dt as DT,
                               0 as \"Nombre OCO\",
                               0 as \"Nombre Operateur\"
                FROM vue_cdc_for_opera
                    INNER JOIN cdc_postgresql ON vue_cdc_for_opera.code_cdc = cdc_postgresql.code_cdc
                    INNER JOIN dt_bdd_produit ON vue_cdc_for_opera.id_dt = dt_bdd_produit.id_dt
                    ORDER BY " . $order . " " . $sortOrder . "
                    OFFSET :offset
                    LIMIT :limit
```

In order to obtain the "Nombre Operateur", I run the following query:

```
  SELECT
            COUNT(o.id) as \"Nombre Opérateurs\"
            FROM habilitation
            INNER JOIN operateur o ON habilitation.id_operateur = o.id and o.actif = true
            WHERE habilitation.id_cdc_postgresql = :idCdc
            AND habilitation.actif = true
```

in order to obtain the "Nombre OCO", I run the following query:

```
SELECT id_oc, oc FROM vue_for_lien_oco_cdc WHERE oc != '' AND code_cdc = :codeCdc;
```

Essentially I need to recover everything in a single query, to be able to order the "Nombre Operateur" and "Nombre OCO" in the server-side pagination, and it's a above my current SQL skills.
The `:params` refer to binded params later in the PHP code.

I've been told it could be possible with a built-in SQL function inside the query, but I'm not sure where to start.
Is this doable, would you have any lead or can help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do COALESCE and ON in the first and second queries, using DQL, but for the latest we can have:

```
$qb->createQueryBuilder('o')
->from(<insert your entity class here>)
->where('o.oc <> ""')
->andWhere('o.code_cdc = :codeCdc')->setParameter('codeCdc',$<insert variable for code_cdc>)
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Comment: The latest works! I essentially needs to return all the record from a single query. Thank you for trying to help.